# Data Not Updating Across Page Navigation In Next.js 13 Server Components

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I updated the attendance, but it's displaying previous data when moving to another page.

It appears that the 'att' page could be cached and not triggering the 'getStudents' function, despite using export const revalidate = 0;. How can I address this issue?"

```
// app/page.tsx
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

import style from "./style.module.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <ul className={style.navbar}>
          <li>
            <Link href={"/att"}>att</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

```
// app/att/page.tsx
import React from "react";

import { getStudents } from "@/services/student";
import StudentList from "@/components/StudentList";
import Link from "next/link";

export const revalidate = 0;

async function AttendancePage() {
  const students = await getStudents();
  return (
    <main>
      <Link href={"/"}>Back</Link>
      <h1>Attendance</h1>
      <StudentList students={students} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default AttendancePage;
```

```
// services/student.ts
"use server";
import prisma from "@/prisma";

export const getStudents = async () => {
  try {
    const students = await prisma.student.findMany({
      orderBy: {
        name: "asc",
      },
    });
    return students;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```